# Compared to 3-port circulator, what is the use of 4 port circulator?

Tags: circuit-analysis, isolation

What is the use of 4 port circulator, compared to a 3 port circulator?

Comment: 1 extra feature for isolation

Comment: I cannot get you.

Comment: A simple web image search will tell U the  answers http://www.rfcafe.com/references/electrical/ew-radar-handbook/circulators-diplexers.htm